# Activerecord reputation system - nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to follow this video [railscast #364](http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system) but I am having a lot of trouble with my nested routes. When I use this code:

```
<%= link_to "up", vote_movie_review_path(@movie, @reviews, type: "up"), method: "post" %>
```

I get this error when I select up vote:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ReviewsController#vote 

Couldn't find Review with 'id'=# <Review::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f0358c1e550>
```

This is my route:

```
vote_movie_review POST   /movies/:movie_id/reviews/:id/vote(.:format) genre_linkers#vote
```

I created another model that was not nested using this code:

```
<%= link_to "up", vote_movie_path(movie, type: "up"), method: "post" %>
```

and that one worked. So I am thinking it has to be something wrong with my path or how I am calling the objects. I have spent almost all day working on this, I really need help.

**review_controller.rb**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_movie
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :html

  def index
    @reviews = Review.all
    respond_with(@reviews)
  end

  def show

  end

  def vote
    value = params[:type] == "up" ? 1 : -1
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    @review.add_evaluation(:vote, value, current_user)
    redirect_to :back, notice: "thanks for the vote"
  end


  def new
    @review = Review.new
    respond_with(@review)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    @review.movie_id = @movie.id

    if @review.save
      redirect_to @movie
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @review.update(review_params)
    respond_with(@review)
  end

  def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_with(@review)
  end

  private
  def set_review
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_movie
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
  end

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:genre, :description, :vote)
  end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :movies do 
    resources :reviews  do 
      member { post :vote }
    end
  end

   root 'movies#index'


end
```

and the model
**review.rb**

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :movie

   has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
end
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a routes problem. As the error message says, the error is in `ReviewsController#vote`. Please post the code for that method, along with the line number from the error message.

Comment: The error is from line 18 @review = Review.find(params[:id]) I am still a noob and that also means learning how to ask questions :)

Comment: would be nice to show your models as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is this part of your link_to: `vote_movie_review_path(@movie, @reviews, type: "up")`. @reviews is an ActiveRecord::Relation and not a Review record, hence no record with an ID can be found.

Comment: Please edit your original question with the answer or accept the proper answer so people in the future can find the answer if they have a similar problem.

Comment: Simon, you did answer my question, but I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer.